# Filtering out nested sub-rows without using index in Tableau?

Tags: filter, tableau-api

[Nested Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b20Wo.png)

For example, how would I filter out all the issues per company that have less than 2,000 counts? I've done it with index but that only shows N amount of rows for each company but I want to show rows that have more than 2,000 counts.

[nested rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSedr.png)

Filtering by condition where issue count > 2000 seems to filter out issues that are less than 2,000 through the sum of all counts of that issue when I want to filter it out per company.

Edit: Added in snapshots of data for clarification
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft0pu.png)

[Snapshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpLOV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try using filter on CNT([ISSUE]) instead of [ISSUE].  That should help.

or alternatively use LOD calculation filter (and add it context)

2. filter of calculated field `CF` with TRUE (as >2000)

```
{FIXED [company] : COUNT([ISSUE])} > 2000
```

If these are not working please show me a snapshot of your data